# Geo-distributed Azure App's vs One-region

Tags: azure, geolocation, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure App Service to setup my website. I have 2 Azure App Service instances and 2 Azure SQL.

1 App Service instance is in the Central US and 1 App Service instance Central India. 1 SQL instance is in the Central US and the other is in Central India.

I use Traffic Manager to route traffic to either region.

What confuses me is that, when I access the Indian server directly the page seems to load at pretty much the same speed as the server in the US.

And both seem to load relatively quickly. Around 250-350ms each to load a page with no styling that performs one database query.

Does this mean that deploying in multiple regions is overkill? Would I be better deploying a larger instance in a single region?

Comment: Your sample size is a bit small, since only you are testing :) The main reason to deploy to multiple regions is to get around limitations involving the speed of light, unreliable network segments etc. You might have a good route to both regions, but some people won't.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-region architecture can **provide higher availability** than deploying to a single region.
If a regional outage affects the primary region, you can **use Traffic Manager to fail over to the secondary region**. 
This architecture can also help if an individual subsystem of the application fails.

Also, when you configure you Traffic Manager, **create a health probe endpoint** that reports the overall health of the application and use this endpoint for the health probe.

The endpoint should **check critical dependencies** such as the App Service apps, storage queue, and SQL Database.

Otherwise, the probe might report a healthy endpoint when critical parts of the application are actually failing.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region).